# How do I change the styling of the default Alert Popup of ion-select?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to include the primary, secondary and tertiary colors I used in the app I am working on and I haven't found a way to do it. but after looking on here and after trying to find an answer on google but to no luck so I am asking here.

I tried looking in the official docs and didn't find anything related to the alert that it uses.

```
<ion-select formControlName="currency">
  <ion-select-option value="btc" checked="true">Bitcoin</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="ethereum">Ethereum</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

It currently looks like this (I can't post images yet so I have to include the link directly)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yWS7.png

while the ionic colors are used for primary, secondary and tertiary are used like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUDfm.png

Is there a way to do this without creating a custom alert?

Comment: <ion-select color="primary" formControlName="currency">
  <ion-select-option value="btc" checked="true">Bitcoin</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="ethereum">Ethereum</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't change anything in the alert sadly.

Comment: check on customizing ionic alert dialog using custom css

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert  go through that well

Comment: So do you think I have to make a custom alert to have the ability to style it? I would be surprised if there is no way of customizing the default alert popups in ionic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that goes in your .ts file

```
 async presentAlert(){ 
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: "My Header",
          message:
            "this is my message.",
            cssClass: "CUSTOMCSS", <<<< place the class name there
          buttons: [
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              role: "cancel",
              cssClass: "secondary",
              handler: blah => {
                // Do something
              }
            },
            {
              text: "Sync",
              handler: () => {
                // Do something
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        await alert.present();
    }
```

then in your global.scss

```
.CUSTOMCSS{
    *{
        ion-item {
           --background: var(--ion-color-primary);
           color: var(--ion-color-dark);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I came to the conclusion that I would have to us a custom alert or another way to select the options either way because the default one is sadly not customizeable however I want to ask how I would use a scss file if the alert I want to create is used in a service/provider?

Comment: Found the solution, I have to include the css in global.scss